# How to get FCMToken from pass Sender ID?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4.2

I'm setting up firebase, but not include firebase.configuration to appdelegate file.

I wan't FCMToken without adding GoogleService-Info file.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {

Messaging.messaging().retrieveFCMToken(forSenderID:"mysendrid") { (fcmToken, error) in

DLog("Got token \(fcmToken!)")

 }
}
```

I expect fcmtoken but token not getting.

Comment: @MartinR no i am passing my Own sender id

Comment: you can not get fcmToken without configuring GoogleService-Info file. please follow each steps in this link to get fcmToken : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: @DhavalBhimani already working since last 1 year but currently not working...